# jest error failed to load component in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs, styled-components, ts-jest

i have a component called NavLinks , ant this is my styled component:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

export const Wrapper = styled.nav`
    ${({ theme }) => css`
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    background-color:${theme.colors.primaryColor};

    @media ${theme.media.lteMedium} {
      flex-flow: column wrap;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    `}

`;
```

and in the jest, i'm just testing if all Menu links are good

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { renderTheme } from '../../styles/render-theme';
import { NavLink, NavLinkProps } from '.';
import { Mock } from './Mock';

const props: NavLinkProps = {
  links: [{ link: '', newTab: false, children: '' }],
};

describe('<NavLink />', () => {
  it('should render all MenuItens', () => {
    renderTheme(<NavLink {...props} links={Mock} />);
    expect(screen.getAllByRole('link')).toHaveLength(Mock.length);
  });
});
```

but my jest fail and bring this error

```
FAIL  components/NavLink/test.tsx [ components/NavLink/test.tsx ]
Error: [vite-node] Failed to load components/MenuLink
 ❯ async components/NavLink/index.tsx:2:31
      1| import { MenuLink } from 'components/MenuLink';
      2| import * as Styled from './styles';
       |                               ^
      3| type LinkType = { children: string; link?: string; newTab?: boolean };
      4| export type NavLinkProps = {
```

how can i solve this error?